# Not able to catch the characters ü, ö and ä

Tags: php, html

When trying to upload a file to my web server, I am not able to catch the characters ö, ä, and ü.

```
$s = $_FILES['title']['name'];
var_dump($s); // returns string(11) "hellö.PDF"
var_dump(strpos($s, 'h') !== false); // returns bool(true)
var_dump(strpos($s, 'e') !== false); // returns bool(true)
var_dump(strpos($s, 'l') !== false); // returns bool(true)
var_dump(strpos($s, 'ö') !== false); // returns bool(false)
```

The header of my page includes `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

What is the problem here?

**Edit:**

Even `var_dump(mb_strpos(utf8_encode($s), 'ö') !== false);`returns `false`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php

Comment: Is your PHP file saved also saved in utf-8?

Comment: Although the charset needs to be properly set throughout the application too. But generally speaking, `mb_*` functions should be used when dealing with multibyte strings, see [live demo](https://3v4l.org/16R71)

Comment: @Qirel I have also tried using `mb_strpos` but I still get the same result.

Comment: @BenHillier yes, my PHP file is saved in UTF8

Comment: `$_FILES['title']['name']` and your text editor are no using the same encoding. Try to find out [which one](http://php.net/bin2hex).

Answer (score 0):

If your text editor is creating Unicode utf-8 files this might work.
Not sure if the filename is in utf-8 by default.

```
<?php
$s = "äöüÄÖÜ";
var_dump(mb_strpos($s, 'ö') !== false);
?>
```

Comment: My editor (Sublime Text) is showing me that the encoding is set to UTF-8 but using your code ends up with the same issue. So I still get `false`.

Comment: Try using http://php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php with source character set iso8859-1 and destination character set utf-8

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap both the string and the character in UTF-8

```
$r = utf8_encode("hellö");
echo strpos($r, utf8_encode('ö')); // 4
```

To find umlauts, best to use regex (regular expressions):

```
echo hasUmlauts(utf8_encode("Händel, Hölle über")); // true
echo hasUmlauts("Händel, Hölle über"); // true
echo hasUmlauts(utf8_encode("HÄNDEL, HÖLLE ÜBER")); // true
echo hasUmlauts("HÄNDEL, HÖLLE ÜBER"); // true
echo hasUmlauts("Something here yadda yadda"); // false

function hasUmlauts($string) {
    return preg_match("/[ÄäÖöÜü]+/", $string);
}
```

Your usage would be:

```
if (hasUmlauts($_FILES['title']['name'])) {
    // If true
} else {
    // If false
}
```

Comment: I did but that makes it even worse. Now my string looks like this: `string(13) "helloÌ.PDF"` and `strpos()` still returns false.

Comment: Something is not being encoded properly. Can I ask why you're looking for the string position offset of certain characters? Perhaps there's a better way of dealing with whatever it is you're attempting.

Comment: Sure, I am just trying to figure out if the characters ä, ö or ü are in `$_FILES['title']['name']`. If you know a better solution, please feel free to suggest it.

Comment: Try running your filename strings through the `hasUmlauts` function above. Works fine on my machine.

Comment: Pro-tip: any answer to encoding questions that suggests using the `utf8_encode()` function is wrong almost for sure. See [the PHP manual](http://php.net/utf8_encode) to learn what it really does (and, yes, it's terribly misnamed).

Comment: When I test your code, all your echos have the correct values but when I use `if (hasUmlauts($_FILES['title']['name']))`, I get to the `else` condition.

Comment: Occam's Razor would suggest the issue lies with encoding somewhere. The code runs as expected on my machine using PHP 5.6.8. Is the HTML page you're submitting this file upload from using UTF-8 in the `<head>`?